# Select attribute value by attribute name of element with xpath using scrapy

Tags: scrapy

```
<meta name="GLOBEL:pageid" id="logsss_pageid" content="x-444511621">
```

Tried response.css('#logsss_pageid').extract()  and got:

```
 ['<meta name="GLOBEL:pageid" id="logsss_pageid" content="x-444511621">']
```

all I need is the **x-444511621**

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
response.css('#logsss_pageid').xpath('@content').get()
```

More info: [selectors in scrapy using xpath](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#id1)